# How can I fetch the post slugs of all languages?

Tags: wordpress, rest, custom-post-type, slug, wpml

I have a react project which fetches data on wordpress via api calls (plugins installed: ACF and WPML).
I have the Event CPT and viewing the page localhost: 3000 / events / first-event, I retrieve the information via the slug.
If on this page I wanted to retrieve the same event in another language, I could add the country code in the url and make a redirect.
It is possible that the same event has different slugs based on the language and the feature does not work.
Do you have any ideas on how to make this feature?

Thank you guys!

I have temporarily modified the pathname.

```
<a href={window.location.pathname.replace('/','/en/')}>EN</a>
```

I have found the **solution**.

I used the `icl_get_languages()` function to fetch the languages, `icl_object_id()` to retrieve the post id of a language, `get_post` to retrieve all fields and `update_post_meta` to add a custom field to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have the same setting but not with React.

If you are using the API without any modifications in the class and given that the title between language is the same try the following:
`/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?post-slug=second+post&lang=fr`
and page slug
`/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/?page-slug=second+post&lang=fr`

However, you need to modify the API response if you want your ACF fields to be there (or use a plugin).

Also mind that post ID between translations is different. Ensure to include the lang as argument in the modification of the WP_REST_Controller. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_controller/get_collection_params/

Let me know if that helps.